How to fill the values of an Enum base on type
I'm trying to create a Character Ability system in Unity.
In the system, I have various different classes and interfaces that all inherent from an empty 'IAbilitySystem' interface.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace TenkayCode
{

    namespace Systems
    {

        public interface IAbility : IAbilitySystem
        {
            [Modifiable]
            string Name { get; }
            [Modifiable]
            float BaseCooldown { get; }
            [Modifiable]
            int BaseCharges { get; }

            void Action() { }

        }

        public interface IReloadableAbility : IAbility
        {
            [Modifiable]
            float ReloadSpeed { get; }
            [Modifiable]
            int MaxAmmo { get; }
            [Modifiable]
            int AmmoPerReload { get; }

            void Reload() { }

            List<IModifier<IReloadableAbility>> Modifiers { get; }
        }

        public interface IOverheatAbility : IAbility
        {
            [Modifiable]
            float MaxHeat { get; }
            [Modifiable]
            float HeatReduceRate { get; }

            void Cooling() { }
            void Heating() { }

            List<IModifier<IOverheatAbility>> Modifiers { get; }
        }

        [CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Assets/Ability")]
        public class TenkayAbility : ScriptableObject, IAbility
        {
            String AbilityName;
            float AbilityCooldown;
            int AbilityCharges;

            public string Name => AbilityName;

            public float BaseCooldown => AbilityCooldown;

            public int BaseCharges => AbilityCharges;
        }

    }

}

Those classes have various fields of float and int datatype that the system uses to calculate how the ability works (i.e. damage, melee range, spread, aoe, projectile speed, etc). Each of these fields is using a custom attribute 'Modifiable'.
I have a 'Stat' interface for containing and calculating a Characters Stat Numbers (i.e. Character HP, Str, % of Missing Mana, Level, etc)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace TenkayCode
{
    namespace Systems
    {

        public interface IStat : IAbilitySystem
        {
            [Modifiable]
            int BaseValue { get; }
            void getBonusFromEquipment() { }
            void getBonusFromBuffs() { }
        }

        public interface IResourceStat : IStat
        {
            [Modifiable]
            float BaseRegenRate { get; }
            List<IModifier<IResourceStat>> Modifiers { get; }

        }

    }
}

I also have a 'Modifier' Class that can take its own Float 'ModRatio' and some number from a 'Stat' Class and augment the values of any 'Modifiable' fields in any class that implements IAbilitySystem whenever that value is being called upon by something else.
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;


namespace TenkayCode
{

    namespace Systems
    {

        [AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
        public sealed class ModifiableAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public ModifiableAttribute() { }
        }

        public class IModifier<T> where T : IAbilitySystem

        {

            IStat ModifierStat;
            [Modifiable]
            float ModRatio;

            /*im pretty sure this is wrong*/
            //   List<IModifier<T>> RatioModifiers { get; }

            /*this is the part where Im stuck at...
            
                        enum ModifierTarget<T> { 

                            // The names of all the fields and properties of type <T> which have the Modifiable Atribute 
                        }
            */
        }

    }
}



I would like to set up this system so that the 'Modifier' class can be used generically (i.e.: Modifier<T> where T : IAbilitySystem).
My thought process is that this would allow me to create a enum in 'Modifier' named 'Modifier Target' that can dynamically fill itself with all of the names of the Fields with the 'Modifiable' attribute pertaining to type 'T'. This would allow me to store all Modifiers for a specific type of 'Ability' into a single list (List<Modifiers<This.Type>> mods), as opposed to having a list for each Field that can be modified and having to make sure that each Mod is in the right List. This would also let me continue to scale the system up to as many IAbilitySystem as I want to without creating too much spaghetti.
My end goal is to be able to create different abilities as scriptable objects in unity and be able to use the inspector to assign base values and edit any modifiers with ease. I like how Unity can list all of the possible values of an enum field in a dropdown menu.
I would like to know if I'm on the right path for the solution or if there is a better way of implementing this kind of system.
Also I would like the 'Modifier' to be able to have its own list of 'Modifiers' as well (i.e.: using Stats to adjust the ModRatio of a Modifier).
I have created basic version the all the classes and interfaces.

If you have a basic version of your code, you probably want to show it (preferably as a [rme]) so that we can better see what you are talking about. Code is the lingua franca on this site

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Sounds like you want to

automatically track existing types either implementing your interface or having a specific attribute.
Usually you would have to use Reflection but luckily Unity already provides exactly that information via the TypeCache

And then generate an enum filled with that information
One way to do so is e.g. simply using an InitializeOnLoadMethod - this gets called when the project is opened or after each recompilation.
And then use simple plain File IO to generate the according script file.


As I didn't grasp your exact needs here just a dummy sample
public static class MyEnumGenerator 
{
    // Adjust according to your needs
    private const string TARGET_FILE_PATH = "TenkayCode/Systems/ModifierTarget.cs";

    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Generate()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("using System;/n/n");
        sb.Append("namespace TenkayCode/n{   public enum ModifierTarget/n   {/n");
 
        // Use method according to your needs here
        foreach(var fieldInfo in TypeCache.GetFieldsWithAttribute(typeof(ModifiableAttribute)))
        {
            sb.Append("       ")
              .Append(fieldInfo.DeclaringType.Name)
              .Append('_')
              .Append(fieldInfo.Name)
              .Append(",/n");
        }

        sb.Append("    }/n}");

        File.WriteAllText(TARGET_FILE_PATH, sb.ToString());
    }
}

Optionally you could additionally generate each enum item with a InspectorNameAttribute replacing the _ by a / in order to get the drop-down nicely grouped by implementing type
In similar ways you can also add your types to lists if needed - this depends a lot on your use case of course.
